# How to change button background and text color under every post

Tags: css, wordpress

How to change the background and text color of every <kbd>read more</kbd> button on [my website](http://investdunia.com)?

The site has "swift" theme.

Comment: You will have to share some coding, what you have tried, and shouldn't just give a link and expect us to fix your site - That being said - it is simple CSS

Comment: example : .btn-default {background-color:#e42d20;}

Comment: how to css? : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a option in Wordpress admin panel to edit website's appearance, including font size, color and stuff like that. I have not worked on the Swift theme but from the little experience I have, theme's options have such features to modify color/size/font without having to write CSS for it.

OR you can add custom CSS to your website, but for that you will need to write CSS which may overlap with other settings on the website if not done carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Read More' element has 'moretext' class, so you need to work on CSS to customize it. Something like this:

```
.moretext { background: #ffffff; color: 000000; }
```

Here's the documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More